# Counting rows in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, prepared-statement

I'm trying to count the number of rows that are returned to `$data` in a wordpress database query that I'm making.  See below

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE wordpress_id=%d",get_current_user_id()),ARRAY_A);
```

The issue that I seem to be running into is the use of a prepared statement.  I figure I could just write a loop to go through the array and tally them up but is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...`. Let the database do the work for you. There's no need to dump *all* of the data over the wire just to get a count.

Comment: Either ^^ or `count($data)` will give you the count.

Comment: @xbonez  Wow, that was easy Many thanks; that was just what I was looking for.  Feel free to put it in a formal answer so I can credit you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the count, change your SQL query to `SELECT COUNT(*) as count ...`. This is efficient since the counting will be done on the database itself, and you won't be fetching all the data through the network.

If, however, you need both the data and the count, fetch the data as you are, and get the count by doing `count($data)`.

Reference: [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: Just remember, if you want a `count` for all records, and retrieve only part of it - 1st query you make with `count(*)` and where (but without LIMIT), and the query for retrieving the data with `limit` and with proper column names (or `*`).